# SQL Query: Distinct Values for the same column repeated 3 times

Tags: sql

I'm working on a query that finds the optimal qty to transfer between warehouses. In a single query, I'm trying to get the Item Code, Reorder Point for items in `WarehouseA`, Reorder point for items in `WarehouseB` and the sum of the reorder points for both `WarehouseA` and `WarehouseB`.

I'm using a GUI so I've tried calling the Item Code field and the ROP (Reorder Point) field 3 times.

```
SELECT ItemCode, ROP, ROP, ROP
FROM Inventory
```

Is there a way that I can filter the 3 ROP fields in a unique way for each one?
E.g. The first ROP field shows the Reorder Point where `whse=A`, the second ROP field shows the reorder point where `whse=B`, and the third reorder point field shows the sum of the two.

Comment: Why are you calling the `ROP` field three times ? The token named `ROP` can refer to only ONE field in the database table.  There CANNOT be three separate fields in the table all named `ROP`.  Did you perhaps mean to type ROPA, ROPB, and ROPC ??  What is schema of `inventory` table?

Comment: Show please the structure of your table

Answer (score 1):

Use inline selects:

```
SELECT
    ItemCode,
    (SELECT ii.ROP FROM Inventory ii WHERE ii.ItemCode = oi.ItemCode AND ii.whse='A') AS ROPA,
    (SELECT ii.ROP FROM Inventory ii WHERE ii.ItemCode = oi.ItemCode AND ii.whse='B') AS ROPB,
    (SELECT ii.ROP FROM Inventory ii WHERE ii.ItemCode = oi.ItemCode AND ii.whse='C') AS ROPC
FROM Inventory oi
```

The above assumes that `ItemCode` is the key.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly:

```
SELECT
    I.ItemCode, 
    WHA.ROP AS A_ROP,
    WHB.ROP AS B_ROP,
    ISNULL(WHA.ROP,0) + ISNULL(WHB.ROP,0) AS Total_ROP
FROM
    Inventory AS I
LEFT JOIN
    WarehouseA AS WHA ON (WHA.ItemCode = I.ItemCode)
LEFT JOIN
    WarehouseB AS WHB ON (WHB.ItemCode = I.ItemCode)
```